# tar exclude file pattern

Tags: file, tar

I am trying to create a tar with follwing command:

```
tar -cvf myFile.tar -X exclude-files.txt myContentDirectory
```

and my exclude-file has follwing patterns to exclude:

```
**/*.bak
**/*.db
**/*.html
```

But i dont see these file types being excluded out in my tar.
What am I doing wrong here?

I found that when i have just one pattern in my exclude-files.txt, lets say only

```
**/*.bak
```

it does work. But not with multiple file patterns (EACH ON NEW LINE)

Comment: What version of tar (and what operating system) are you using?  I tested this using the OSX version (tar 2.8.3) and it works fine ...

Comment: Works fine on FreeBSD 12 also (`bsdtar 3.5.2 - libarchive 3.5.2 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.5 bz2lib/1.0.8`) - I note that the use of `**` in bash shell is governed by the `globstar` shell option (`shopt globstar`) - could some implementation of tar be checking for that? It is off in my shell and tar still handles `**` anyway.

Answer (score 9):

I think this:

```
*.bak
*.db
*.html
```

is the correct format for the exclude file if you want to exclude a particular directory you could do:

```
some-dir/*.db
```

Also your command should look like this:

```
tar -cvf myFile.tar -X exclude-files.txt myContentDirectory
```

Comment: i tried this as well but it worked, what do you get for output when you run the command?

Comment: just edited my question above, please have a look. The command does run, but the exclude option works only if there's only one pattern mentioned in my file.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry if this answer is a little late.

```
tar -cO --exclude=*.bak myContentDirectory | tar -O --delete '*.db' | tar -O --delete '*.html' > myFile.tar
```

See, what you're doing here is creating the tar, but sending it to stdout instead of to a file then piping that into tar to delete the stuff you don't want, one or more times and finally writing the output to a file.

You can even test it first like this:

```
tar -cO --exclude=*.bak myContentDirectory | tar -O --delete '*.db' | tar -O --delete '*.html' | tar -tv
```

Which will spit out a list of all the files remaining in the archive.

Comment: `--exclude` patterns should always be in single quotes e.g. `--exclude='*.bak'`.  see: https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/problems-with-exclude.html

Comment: @thom_nic it is best practice, though technically it is not necessary in the above case: `--exclude=*.bak`. It would be necessary for this form: `--exclude '*.bak'`. The point is to avoid shell expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the order of the command is incorrect.

> tar -cvf myFile.tar -X exclude-files.txt myContentDirectory

should be something like

> tar cv -X exclude-files.txt -f myFile.tar myContentDirectory

PS. I haven't looked into the filters itself. Most likely order of the parameters is the issue.
    If issues is in the filters/patterns - it's easier to test one by one with --exclude option.